# How to click on item in tree view using Watir page-object methods

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have the following HTML which represents a treeview with two elements TREENODE1,TREENODE2:

```
<div id="foldersPodContent" class="body">
    <ul id="foldersTree" class="list collapsible folders hideRoot" data-component-type="tree" data-tab-index="3" style="position: relative;">
        <li id="node1" class="folders node open selected firefinder-match" tabindex="-1">
        <p class="wrap button draggable">
            <b id="handler1" class="icon"></b>
        </p>
        <ul id="node1sub" class="list collapsible">
            <li id="node2" class="folders node closed" tabindex="-1">
                <p id="anonymous_element_1" class="wrap button draggable">
                <b id="handler2" class="icon"></b>
                TREENODE1
                </p>
            </li>
            <li id="node9" class="folders node closed " tabindex="-1">
                <p class="wrap button draggable">
                <b id="handler9" class="icon"></b>
                TREENODE2                    </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This id's named handler2, handler9 represent the plus signs in the tree. My goal is to be able to select one of these plus signs using Watir's page-object gem to cause the tree to epand.. The following Ruby code provides access to the text of the two elements TREENODE1, TREENODE2:
`unordered_list(:folders, :id => 'foldersTree')`

This returns a string TREENODE1\nTREENODE2 which can easily be split. Not sure how I get the "handler" items so I can click on them to expand the tree nodes and show subordinates. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The `b` element causes a bit of problems since there is currently nested element method for the `b` element or generic element. As a work around, I think you would have to step down into the underlying Watir code.

Assuming you have defined the folder tree in your page object:

```
unordered_list(:folders, :id => 'foldersTree')
```

Then you could get a specific folder by its text and its expand icon (ie `b` element) with the underlying Watir element:

```
folder = page.folders_element.list_item_element(:text => 'TREENODE1')
folder.element.b.click
```

Comment: Thank you. This saved me a lot of time as I'm not sure how many alternatives I'd try before getting to this ... if ever.